# How can a constant mass flow rate of air coming out of a compressed air tank be maintained?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, air

If I have an air tank filled with air at, say, 4 bar, how would I be able to maintain a constant mass flow rate coming out of that tank, with the air flowing out into the atmosphere?  I would imagine you increase the orifice as the internal pressure of the tank decreases.  What equations would I use to describe the increase in orifice area?

Comment: Google 'choked flow' - but be careful where the cross-over is between the high pressure difference and low pressure difference is for you case. Better perhaps to use a pressure regulator to hold a steady pressure for as long as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a *pressure regulator*, which will automatically choke the flow out of the tank so as to maintain a nearly-constant output pressure as the tank empties itself. These devices are used throughout the engineering world to maintain constant outlet pressure regardless of source pressure.